Infinite scroll working on Chrome and Mozilla (localhost), but it is glitching on Safari. what am I doing wrong?
I'm working on a website with 9 sections and implemented an infinite scroll feature. When you reach the last section, the first one is added to the bottom of the page. This works fine in most browsers, but I'm encountering issues in Safari and on mobile devices after deploying to Heroku. I'm using Rails and Stimulus
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus";

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["section", "selectedImage", "dropbtn", "navbar"];
  sectionIds = ["section1", "section2", "section3", "section4", "section5", "section6", "section7", "section8", "section9"];

  connect() {
    this.prevScrollpos = window.scrollY;
    this.navbarTarget.style.transform = "translateY(-100%)";
    this.scrollHandler = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
    this.infiniteScrollHandler = this.checkInfiniteScroll.bind(this);
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.scrollHandler);
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.infiniteScrollHandler);
    this.observeSections();
  }

  disconnect() {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.scrollHandler);
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.infiniteScrollHandler);
  }

  handleScroll() {
    let currentScrollPos = window.scrollY;
    if (this.prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
      this.navbarTarget.style.top = "0";
    } else {
      this.navbarTarget.style.top = "100px";
    }
    this.prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
  }

  toggleDropdown() {
    const dropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    dropdown.style.display = dropdown.style.display === "block" ? "none" : "block";
  }

  scrollToSection(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const imageSrc = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-image-src");
    this.selectedImageTarget.src = imageSrc;

    this.toggleDropdown();
    const sectionClassName = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("href").substring(1);
    const sectionName = event.currentTarget.innerText;
    const contentHTML = `<img src="${imageSrc}" alt="" class="dot"> ${sectionName}`;

    this.dropbtnTarget.innerHTML = contentHTML;

    const sections = document.getElementsByClassName(sectionClassName);

    if (sections.length > 0) {
      const section = sections[0];

      this.element.querySelectorAll("a").forEach((link) => {
        link.classList.remove("active");
      });

      event.currentTarget.classList.add("active");

      section.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
        block: "center",
        inline: "nearest",
      });
    }
  }

  updateDropdownButton(sectionName, imageSrc) {
    const contentHTML = `<img src="${imageSrc}" alt="" class="dot"> ${sectionName}`;
    this.dropbtnTarget.innerHTML = contentHTML;
  }

  observeSections() {
    const observerOptions = {
      root: null,
      rootMargin: '0px',
      threshold: 0.95
    };

    const observerCallback = (entries, observer) => {
      entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          const section = entry.target;
          const sectionName = section.getAttribute('data-section-name');
          const imageSrc = section.getAttribute('data-image-src');
          this.updateDropdownButton(sectionName, imageSrc);
        }
      });
    };

    this.observer = new IntersectionObserver(observerCallback, observerOptions);
    this.observeAllSections();
  }

  observeAllSections() {
    this.sectionIds.forEach(id => {
      const section = document.getElementById(id);
      if (section) {
        this.observer.observe(section);
      }
    });
  }

  checkInfiniteScroll() {
    if (!this.infiniteScrollPending) {
      this.infiniteScrollPending = true;
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        this.infiniteScrollPending = false;
        const buffer = 50; // Add a small buffer
        if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY + buffer) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
          this.moveFirstSectionToBottom();
        }
      });
    }
  }

  moveFirstSectionToBottom() {
    const firstSection = document.getElementById(this.sectionIds[0]);
    if (firstSection) {
      firstSection.parentNode.appendChild(firstSection);
      this.sectionIds.push(this.sectionIds.shift());
      this.observer.disconnect();
      this.observeAllSections();
    }
  }
}


I'm encountering issues - can you describe them

When the scrollbar reaches the bottom of the page, all the sections glitch rapidly on the screen. I'm new to all of this so I appreciate the help

Add information to the question- don’t bury it in a comment
